# Code logic for a graphical interface based on pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, django, user-interface

I am looking for a good way to create a custom graphical interface that allows for a condition-based evaluation of a pandas dataframe.

For example, a user might want to customize the following condition `df.A > df.B` to `df.A < df.B`. In other instances, they may refer to different column names.

This is easy with a command-line interface, but how can I incorporate this into a graphical tool?

For the above example, I am thinking of a pseudocode similar to this:

```
if text = 'df.A > df.B':
    df['result'] = df.A > df.B
elif text = 'df.B > df.A':
    df['result'] = df.B > df.A

#and so on
```

FYI, this will be a web app.

Thank you.

Comment: if you require user input via the browser you will need to have a html form, otherwise tkinter might something for you

Comment: @Jonas `text` above will refer to the input in an html form. the question, what is the best way to parse the user's input instead of writing if-else statements to cover the different possible column names.

Comment: You have to be careful regarding security issues, but if this is something for yourself and you just want a generic query interpreter you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to directly evaluate Python expressions like `df.A > df.B` from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust your users input, use DataFrame.query https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

```
# text = 'A > B'
df['result'] = df.query(text)
```

If you do not trust your users, you have to sanitize their input first